# Fit Multiple Linear Regression line and calculate residuals from another data in R

Tags: r

I have 3d data for which I want to fit a regression line (I use `lm(x1 ~ x2+x3)`).
To calculate the distances for each point from the line I use `residuals(fit)`.

The question is how can I calculate the distances (residuals) for another set of points from the fitted line from before?

Comment: have you tried anything?? Then please put your code here

Answer (score 0):

Fit a regression plane and print residuals:

```
data(trees)
fit <- lm(Volume ~ Girth + Height, data=trees)
(res <- with(trees, Volume - (fit$coefficients[[3]]*Height + fit$coefficients[[2]]*Girth + fit$coefficients[[1]]))) # = residuals(fit)
```

Now with new data:

```
trees_new <- trees * runif(nrow(trees))
(res_new <- with(trees_new, Volume - (fit$coefficients[[3]]*Height + fit$coefficients[[2]]*Girth + fit$coefficients[[1]])))
```